# Lightweight setup for hosting 1000 domains (DNS & Redirect)

Tags: domain-name-system, debian

How much RAM is needed to host 1000 domains?

Also, which is the most lightweight DNS daemon I can install on a Debian server? The DNS will be very basic (only an A record).

I'm hoping to use as least as possible, as my budget is not very big. There will also be a web server running on the same machine (serving a basic PHP redirect).

And, considering I only have 1 IP, is there any service offering free secondary DNS?

Comment: How long is a peice of string? What are you doing with these domains? If there are 1000 domains all pointing to a single holding page, not very much. If they are 1000 domains all running ecommerce apps then lots. Your going to need to be much more specific about your question or it will be closed.

Comment: It will be a basic PHP redirect; however, I'm wondering about the DNS side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of domains is somewhat insignificant, it's more about the number of records. I'm familiar with BIND, and it doesn't take much memory to run. [ServerFault's](http://serverfault.com) [George Beech](https://serverfault.com/users/5880/zypher) has written a couple [Blog Articles about their DNS](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/category/dns/); including [some sizing information](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/1351746720/). If there are a few records in each domain, you should be looking at <100MB to run BIND 9.x.

There are free secondary DNS services. They probably will not object to you registering a lot of domains with them; but if queries to those domains generate a noticeable amount of traffic they're probably going to want to work out some sort of payment (bandwidth is the enemy of free services like that). I use [afraid.org](http://afraid.org) and [buddyns.com](http://buddyns.com).